# restart jboss on adding jar file in lib folder

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am working with 4 instance of JBoss AS 7 in cluster.

If I develop an class to be deployed as a library and deploy the jar file in server/all/lib folder, Do I have to restart jboss?

Also do I have to copy the file on each server of the cluster and restart each instance of Jboss.